# 'Handshake inactivity timeout' using TypeOrm and AWS RDS Aurora MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, typeorm

Trying to connect to AWS RDS Aurora DB MySQL using TypeOrm and it gives me `Handshake inactivity timeout` error.

```
code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
fatal: true,
timeout: 10000
```

Tried using default 10sec and my own 15sec timeout.

`ormconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "host connection string",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "xxxx",
    "password": "xxxx",
    "database": "xxxx",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "connectTimeout": 15000,
    "entities": [
       "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
       "src/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
       "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
       "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
       "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
       "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
}
```

Able to connect to the instance using Linux MySQL client CLI and even tried connecting to the databse using ECS in same VPC but got same error.

Comment: how did you manage to solve the error? i'm having one exactly like this one.

Answer (score 0):

The most common course of this problem - is wrong settings of your vpc and security group rules. Try to write in/out bound rules for it.

Useful links:
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#DefaultSecurityGroup
*https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html